# Auto populate field with appropriate data

Tags: sharepoint-online

Need your support on this.

We have a sharepoint list having number of fields. I am requesting a solution here.

We have two fields.

Field-1 : Department (Sales)
Field-2 :system Configuration: (i5,500 GB HDD, 8 GB RAM - for sales)
                             : (i5, 256 GB SSD, 8 GB RAM - for operations)

Resoulation required: If i select department "sales", It should take automatically system configuration field with "i5,500 GB HDD, 8 GB RAM". Like wise if department is selected "Operation" it should take system configuration field with "i5, 256 GB SSD, 8 GB RAM". Would be great help if system configuration field will be readonly.

Comment: No, it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery for classic view.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('select[title="System Configuration"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $('select[title="Department"]').change(function () {
                var selectedValue = $(this).val();

                if (selectedValue == "Sales") {
                    $("select[title='System Configuration']").val('i5,500 GB HDD, 8 GB RAM'); 
                } else {
                    $("select[title='System Configuration']").val('i5, 256 GB SSD, 8 GB RAM'); 
                }
            })
        })

    </script>
```

Comment: it is not working. Lee

Comment: make sure the title&values matches, I did test in my environment.

Comment: Lee, You are just awasome, It is working fine now. Can you please check previous post and help me on that.